# Questions on dynamoDB query result

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk, nosql

I'm currently thinking about how I should write my queries for DynamoDB. I have questions below which I hope someone could advise me on it.

**Given scenarios: I have a million records on a table.**

Questions:

1. When I query, can I fetch 1000 records in batches instead of 1 million records at one go?
2. Is the time taken to fetch 1000 records similar to 1 million records?
3. What happens if I hit the limit of 1MB or my throughput for the table so that I can fetch again for the remaining records?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) Yes you can specify a limit for a query (1000 in your case).
2) No. The time is not the same. More records will mean more time - because you will need to fetch more pages (most time will be spend in network roundtrips)
3) If you hit the 1MB limit, Dynamo will provide a LastEvaluatedKey. You repeat the request and pass the LastEvaluatedKey until you fetch everything (you are basically fetching in a loop).
If you hit the provisioned throughput limits, you either increase the limits or you back off (i.e. you need to regulate your consumption to stay within the limits)

Reference: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Query.html

Comment: 1) So how do i start from 1001th records and fetch again? By using LastEvaluatedKey?

2) So that means the function "query" will hang there till the 1million record is fetched before returning the result to me?

Comment: 1) You make a call saying query with limit = 1000. you get results + a last key. You make another call saying query with limit=1000 and exclusiveStartKey = lastKey from previous call. Dynamo will start feeding results from the last key not from the beginning. you continue doing this until you retrieve everything. 2) no. I was talking about total time it takes to retrieve 1 million entries, not one call. see 1) in this comment

Comment: if i make a single query call each for 1000 and 2000 records, will the timing be the same? As I understand, it is a hash table so the timing should be the same like O(1).

Comment: well... sort of. dynamo still has to collect the items and ship them + network transfer time will be larger. but yes, in principle